# Python: Получить первый день месяца, зная последний

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть исходный DF:

```
Data
28.02.1962
31.03.1962
30.04.1962
```

И необходимо получить:

```
Data
01.02.1962
01.03.1962
01.04.1962
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
        Data
0 1962-02-28
1 1962-03-31
2 1962-04-30

In [17]: df.Data - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
Out[17]:
0   1962-02-01
1   1962-03-01
2   1962-04-01
Name: Data, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

df.Data - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1) не будет работать для даты, совпадающей с началом месяца

```
In [71]:  df['Month_begin'] = df['Date'] - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
          df

Out [71]:

    Date        Month_begin
0   2019-07-02  2019-07-01
1   2019-07-01  2019-06-01
2   2019-06-30  2019-06-01
3   2019-07-14  2019-07-01
```